# how to use a "distinct" keyword in the json body below in POSTMAN

Tags: json, get, postman

Here is the below sample body for my service for SELECT query. In the below json I use type: "select" for my SELECT keyword. In the same way how can I use DISTINCT keyword?

This is my sample query SELECT DISTINCT last_name FROM users;

```
{
    "requests": [
    {
    "id": 0,
    "datasets": [
    ],
    "server": "sample server",
    "database": "POSDATA",
    "type": "select",
    "table": "Countries"
    }
    ]
    }
```

Comment: What technology are you useing to parse the string into a SQL query? It is an REST server or something?

Comment: it's rest server @CarlosLópez

Comment: Ok so then i don't understand why you set the query in the json either in the @ get or @ post request... Nevermind, why can't you just make a new attibute called "distinct" : "true" or "distinct" : "false" and use it as identifier?

Comment: sorry, I just checked back we use java in the backend to parse this json to build a sql query. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: We don't know how your java backend parsing works, but you can try ` "type": "select distinct",`